# QGIS displaying features in reversed order

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I loaded in a .shp and went to inspect the attribute table, the features are listed as follows:

```
#  Attr_1  Attr_2
1       3       C
2       2       B
3       1       A  <--- hover shows "Feature ID: 0"
```

The table in ArcGIS however shows them in the order they are in their respective files:

```
#  Attr_1  Attr_2
1       1       A
2       2       B
3       3       C
```

I'm exploring QGIS so this was an interesting find. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Attribute tables are displayed in no specific order. Do not get confused between the row id (always from 1 to N in ascending order) and the feature ID, which can be any value.

For example, if you select 10 random features and display them in the attribute table, the row ID will be from 1 to 10.

If you want the table to be ordered, you need to explicitly sort it.

Comment: Why is that the default? What benefit is there to have no order to a table in which its source is specifically ordered and formatted?

Comment: @pstatix that could be a nice feature request

Comment: Because all sources are not ordered, like all layers/tables stored in a database.

Comment: The benefit is to not loose time ordering a table if the user does not care about such order